# How do I write remote machine Path in askopenfilename

Tags: python, ubuntu, raspberry-pi, selection, paramiko

I am writing a program in python on **Ubuntu**, to remove a file from remote machine(raspberrypi) by accessing it, connected with network.
For file selection I am using a command called **askopenfilename**.
But I am struggling in specifying the Path of RaspberryPi correctly.

Can you please guide me on how do I specify Raspberrypi path correctly?

```
IP = "192.168.2.34"
Username = "pi"
Password ="raspberry"
Path="/home/pi/python"
```

Below is my code

```
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename
import paramiko

client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect('192.168.2.34', username='pi', password='raspberry')

checkdir = "/home/pi/python"
name1= askopenfilename(title = "Select File For Removal", initialdir = checkdir)
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('ls -l')
for line in stdout:
   print '... ' + line.strip('\n')
client.close()
```

Comment: Why is the specified path wrong? You might also consider posting over at http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: because I am trying to access remote machine, which include `IP address` or might be `Network address` as well, I m not sure

Answer (score 1):

I am fairly sure the tk file dialog is only able to browse the Ubuntu machine (which it seems to run on) filesystem - not the RPi filesystem over SSH, so you will never see RPi directories.

if You can read the RPi directory listing there, so you could create your own file browser component or try to find an existing one that works over SSH.

Then again it looks like you are 'inventing the wheel again' (which of course is ok for learning purposes) - gFTP, FileZilla, many of the Linux desktop file browsers etc. (or WinSCP if you were using a Windows box) are ready made tools for this.